# SOAP web service UI

Tags: soap, user-interface

I need to interface a SOAP web service and, for demonstration purposes, I also need to show the API functionality in a graphical user interface.

I would like this interface to be simple, sleek and nice looking.

What's the best technology to create this UI? I'm familiar with Java, Javascript, CSS, HTML, XML, PHP, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is are a bunch of different options. You can create an application from scratch using the technologies above.

I personally recommend the playframework at http://www.playframework.org, it provides a lightweight and easy to use Web Service API.

See http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/libs#WebServiceclient for details.

PHP is also a very good option, but I think you will get up to speed faster with Play.

Node.js is another excellent option...

Not sure how far you need to go with your UI, if it's just a matter of showing the message being sent and the answer, SOAPui may be enough, there is osx SOAP Client and REST client for mac.